# How to use people picker control using sp-pnp-js( Pnp-JS-Core) library and save users selection in Person or Group type column in Sharepoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, pnp-js-core

As I am new to Sharepoint framework, I wan to know how can I use the people picker control using sp-pnp-js library and save the users selection in Person or Group type column in Sharepoint List....

I want to know this with "No javascript" approach not with @pnp/spfx-controls-react....

Answer (score 0):

PnP [People Picker Control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/PeoplePicker/) is a React component it cannot be used in 'no js framework'. You could use legacy js libraries for classic view to create people picker field in no framework SPFx solution if you do need this.

Demo code:

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/SharedSPFx/blob/master/nojsframework/src/webparts/nojsframwork/NojsframworkWebPart.ts

[image]

More reference:

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18424414-ee7d-4500-8c16-9ea152145d5a/how-to-create-a-people-picker-field-in-webpart-using-spfx-no-javascript-framework?forum=SP2019